# Center text in overlay square without opacity

Tags: html, css

I created a square which has a background image and I overlay it with an extra div, and on top of that div I want to have text. Now I thought I could get it right by using `z-index` and `position: relative` but it did not work. The goal is to get the text on top of the black overlay.

Please keep in mind that I do not want to downscale the opacity of the text.

Here is my code and for a demo see here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pqr0gpLt/)

```css
.image-holder {
  width: 275px;
  height: 274px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 13;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2.offer-image-title {
  color: red;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 32%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

.offer-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.offer-1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.wnd.com/files/2015/03/chuck_norris300x300-275x275.jpg);
}

.overlay-black {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 14;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="offer-image offer-1">
    <div class="overlay-black"></div>
    <h2 class="offer-image-title">Chuck Norris</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient()` + `rgba()` for the overlay along with the background image, and center the text with flexbox.

```css
.image-holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFpk9.jpg);
  background-size: 100%, cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <h2>Chuck Norris</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your h2 needs absolute positioning and a top/left location:

```
h2.offer-image-title {
 color: red;
 border: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 36px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 32%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 15;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I created a square which has a background image which I overlay with an extra  and on top of that div I want to have text.

One solution is to have your `h2` sit *inside* the nested `div`:

```css
.image-holder{
 width:275px;
 height:274px;
 display:inline-block; 
 position:relative; 
 z-index:13;
 background-color:blue;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
h2.offer-image-title{
    width: 100%;
 color:red;
 border:0;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:36px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 padding-top:32%; 
 position:relative;
 z-index:15;
}
.offer-image{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
.offer-1{ 
 background-image: url(http://www.wnd.com/files/2015/03/chuck_norris300x300-275x275.jpg);
}
.overlay-black{
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:14;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <div class="offer-image offer-1">       
    <div class="overlay-black">
      <h2 class="offer-image-title">Weight lifting</h2>
    </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: After seeing your comment on the other answer, I removed the `opacity` rule from the inner `div` and instead used an `rgba` value for the `background-color` to achieve the same result but without affecting the opacity of the `h2`. Also, adding `width:100%` to the `h2` will make the `text-align: center` work.